# /bin/sh RHEL6 source not working

Tags: sh

we have a build environ which sources a script for few environment settings as follows

```
if test -f build_env
then
# Source the config file
. build_env
```

but some how this seems to be failing in RHEL6

```
sh-4.1$ . build_env
sh: .: build_env: file not found
```

while in RHEL4 it works

```
sh-3.00$ . buildenv
sh-3.00$
```

what could be the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Try `. ./build_env` (notice './').

Also, your *if* syntax is doubtful, though I can't be sure until you fix formatting in the question. I would write it like this:

```
if test -f build_env; then . ./build_env; fi
```